# Audience Targeting to other Site Collection

Tags: 2016, site-collection, audience-targeting

**Scenario:**

Site Collection A - Everyone landing/home page

Site Collection B - Finance

Site Collection C - HR

Site Collection D - IT

Each of the site collection has unique permission and groups.

> Finance Owner, Finance Member, Finance Visitor
>
> HR Owner, HR Member, HR Visitor
>
> IT Owner, IT Member, IT Visitor

**Question**

How to setup navigation links in landing/homepage for Site Collection B/C/D with their respective SharePoint groups as target audience.

Answer (score 0):

Audience targeting cannot be done using SharePoint groups in general, much less SharePoint groups in another site collection.  Active Directory groups are available for audience targeting, so if available, use them.

Ref: [Audience and content targeting planning (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc261958(v=office.14))

Note, the reference is SP 2010, but applies equally to 2013/2016/online.